# For remote development using VS Code, when I perform a GIT clone how does the repository get to the remote computer?

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, git-clone

This is more of a security question: I am running VS Code on my Windows laptop and working with a repository on a Linux computer that VS Code is SSH'd into. I installed a VS Code GIT extension, GitHub Pull Requests and Issues, and was able to clone a repository onto the remote computer.

My access to GitHub is via a secure connection using the SSH keys on my computer (I give VS Code an https URL). VS Code then prompts for my user name and personal access key (that I set up in Git).

My coworkers don't use VS Code. They enter the GIT clone command directly on the remote Linux computer, and use SSH Agent forwarding to relay the user authentication challenge from GitHub back to the local computer they are working on.

My question: Is VS Code using SSH Agent forwarding in the backgound, or is the repository being cloned transferred first to my laptop (that is running VS Code), and then via SSH to the remote Linux computer (that is running a VS Code server)? Or is the secure cloning done some other way entirely?

Comment: if the whole repository would be cloned to your local machine first would be a great security risk. You have to execute the clone command on the remote machine.

Comment: I can't say what VS Code is doing, but the sane thing to do would be to use `ssh` to run `git clone` on the remote machine. It would have to do the same to run any `git` commands on the remote repository. What, exactly, is this extra VS Code Git extension that allows working directly on remote servers, because it sounds very useful.

Comment: Schwern: You can run VS Code on your local computer to develop (write and debug) code on a remote computer via SSH. When VS Code connects to another computer it installs a lightweight server on that remote computer that only exists in volatile memory. The GIT extension installs on the remote computer, and facilitates GIT operations on the remote computer from within the VS Code IDE on the local computer. I run VS Code on Windows to write code on Linux test stations (Disclaimer: I might be wrong on the details) Given your reputation score you likely have a better idea of how this works.